# why cannot append element into list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
 val df3 = df.flatMap( r => {r.toString().split(",").filter(line=>line.contains(PREFIX)) })
   // df3.show(100,false)

    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    val df4= df3.map(line =>(line.split(" TO ")(1).trim)->line.split(" TO ")(0).trim)
     val lss = new ListBuffer[String]()
    df4.foreach {
      row => {println(row._1); lss += (row._1) }
    }
    print(lss.size) // this code produce the size of list is zero.
  }
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

0 //size of list
```

Updated the types

[image]

## I have solved with this solution , thanks you  everyone for tricks.

```
df3.map(line => (line.split(" TO ")(1).trim) -> line.split(" TO ")(0).trim).collect().toMap
```

trick is using `collect().toMap()`

Comment: I checked in my IDE an example similar to this, and it worked correctly. Can you tell me what is the type of `row._1`?

Comment: I updated the question with types

Comment: Basically, your list is serialized to the executors, where the elements are added. The version on the driver remains untouched. Try using a collection accumulator that are made for your use case. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is an action and will be executed on the executors while `lss` is a value on the driver. Hence, `lss` is not affected.

To modify `lss`, you can move the data to the driver by [collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@collect():Array[T]) or [toLocalIterator()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@toLocalIterator():java.util.Iterator[T]) and then append.